# shutdown switch T default

Tags: windows

I ask after looking it up in Microsoft web pages.

They say the T option has a default of 30 seconds.

I tried this cmd, but the terminal does not respond to it.

Instead, it presents the help page of the shutdown cmd.
It seems like there is no default value to T option.

Did I miss anything ?

```
Shutdown /R /T /F
```

Comment: Why do you use uppercase? `/t` sets the timeout, but you haven't specified a timeout https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown  If the timeout period is greater than 0, the /f parameter is implied. What you want is probably `shutdown /r /f /t 0`

Comment: They specify a default time of 30 seconds.
It's not my own claim....but theirs's.

Comment: You put them in the wrong order for the default to work `shutdown /r /f /t` probably shuts the computer down after 30s (but I am not gonna test it)

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't work, but thank you.

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Answer (score 0):

`/t` has to be the last flag. So in your example, you'd execute `shutdown /r /f /t` after which you'll get a Windows notification to tell you the machine is going to reboot at `time now + 30 seconds`.

If you want to reboot immediately, you need to pass a value for `t` in seconds. You would therefore execute `shutdown /r /f /t 0`. If you want to reboot in 5 minutes, you'd execute `shutdown /r /f /t 300`.

Also, `/f` isn't mandatory, it just forces running applications to close. In fact when using `/t`, `/f` is implied.

Also note, that passing in `/t` with no value doesn't work, and you'll be presented with the list of valid parameters. `/t` expects you to provide a value in seconds between 0-315360000 (10 years).

Comment: yeah thats what i said, right?

Comment: Yes, in a comment. I've made it an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> They say the T option has a default of 30 seconds

"Option has a default of..." is context-dependent. The /T option does not activate a new feature (there will still be a shutdown timer if you omit the option), it only changes the settings of an already-active feature – therefore it requires a value, and the default applies when the option is **not** specified at all. There will still be a shutdown timer if you omit the option, and it'll be set to 30 seconds by default.

Options that *do* activate a new feature, with an optional value that has a default, would usually be written as `/x:yz` or `/xyz` when the value is specified (to avoid ambiguity when the value starts with a slash).

Comment: I really don't want to bother anyone but it makes no sense.
I think this is all a mistake.
The T option has no default value at all.

Comment: Yes, the option doesn't, but *the parameter controlled by that option* does, and the documentation has slightly imprecise wording that doesn't correctly distinguish between the two cases. Most readers are able to infer it from context.

Comment: Run `shutdown /?` and scroll down to `/t`. It literally says, /t xxx   Set the time-out period before shutdown to xxx seconds. The valid range is 0-315360000 (10 years), ***with a default of 30***. If the timeout period is greater than 0, the /f parameter is implied.

Comment: I say the default part of T option does not exist.
It's a gross mistake.

Comment: Then raise a ticket with Microsoft...

Comment: I forgot to say, any statement about the switches order is not true.
Microsoft say nothing about it, and all switches combinations work as expected.

Comment: Reading this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown the syntax DOES indicate there is an order. /t can only come before /d and /c, it cannot come before any other arguments.

Comment: Hate to argue, but any order works.

Comment: @RoniKed you need to be taking these issues up with Microsoft, not complaining to us. Your question isn't clear, and there have been 2 attempts to answer it, neither of which you have voted on/marked as the correct answer. What are you expecting here?

Comment: I said exactly what I had in mind.
The T default. does not exist.
The order of switches, Irrelevant in practice.
Upper or lower case, Irrelevant in practice.
I'm not complaining. I talk facts only.
Not complaining.

Comment: @RoniKed who said any flags were case sensitive?